# Dark mode for Movies & TV?

Tags: feature-request

I'm a user of stackoverflow (just recently created an account but have been using it for years) and IIRC somewhat recently they've come out with a dark mode (and/or at least, I've recently enabled it). When I switch between SO and Movies&TV it gives me a visual whiplash... that being said, **do we know/think that Movies&TV will ever get a dark mode as well?**

Comment: Oh, hell no!!!!

Comment: Lol, not a fan of dark mode Nap?

Comment: I actually consider it one of the worst wastes of developer time on SE ever and detrimental to everyone involved. But...your opinion may differ. ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't a dark-mode M&TV be basically SFF?

Comment: As a light-sensitive individual, I appreciate the dark mode request. However, my suggestion for other light-sensitive users is to opt for the brightest, whitest display possible, and then invert your colors (it's a lot easier than getting each and every site on the Internet to change). The only problem is pictures are inverted, too. That, and some sites aren't optimized for light-hungry people. ;) (Just most of them.)

Answer (score 5):

Many sites have asked for this:

- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7209/113522)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4779/22845)
- [Chinese Language](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1892/15684)

and of course the Meta Stack Exchange post [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/295232), so I'm going to repeat myself:

At the moment, it is questionable whether Dark Mode will be rolled out to the rest of the network at all. From the [announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits):

> #### Future releases
>
> At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our [styles] easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.

Because there are so many of them, and the design looks much like Stack Overflow, sites without a custom design like beta sites will probably be the first to get Dark Mode (I've even seen one of the Community Managers, Catija, mentioning this, but I can't find it). For sites with a custom design like Movies & TV Stack Exchange I wouldn't hold my hopes up.